# How to create child object inside array on each click in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I want to insert object as a child of existing last object on every click of a button.

This is my code:

```
const Myarray = [
    { id: 1, child:[] }
]

handleArrayDepth = (Myarray) => {

    Myarray.map(arrayitem => {
      let id = arrayitem.id;
      id++;
      arrayitem.child.push({
        id: id,
        child: []
      });
      if (id < 2) {
        this.handleArrayDepth(arrayitem.child);
      }
    });
};
console.log(Myarray);
```

This is log of my initial array.

```
0:{
  id: 1,
  child: []
}
```

If i clicked the button 2 times, i got output like this:

```
0:{
  id: 1,
  child: [
    0:{
      id: 2,
      child: []
    },
    1:{
      id: 3,
      child: []
    }
  ]
}
```

But I want something like below:

```
0:{
  id: 1,
  child: [
    0:{
      id: 2,
      child: [
        0:{
          id: 3,
          child: []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

It should goes on for each click recursively/infinitely. I couldn't find effective way to do this.

Comment: Why on earth are you redefining `Array`? How will you create a `new Array` or check if `Array.isArray`?

Comment: `array` should be `arrayitem`

Comment: I just posted an illustration of my code. This is not an exact code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some problems

- Do not use `Array` as variable name
- Don't use map when you're not returning values from it or mutating values
- `array.id` doesn't makes sense as you don't have any variable named `array` in your original code

You can modify you code a bit, make recursive call if the child length is greater than 0 else push the value

```js
const array = [{id: 1,child: []}]

handleArrayDepth = (arr) => {
  arr.forEach(({id,child}) => {
    id++;
    if (child.length) {
      handleArrayDepth(child);
    } else {
      child.push({id: id, child: [] });
    }
  });
};
handleArrayDepth(array)
handleArrayDepth(array)
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to just have a persistent variable referring to the last inserted object:

```js
const array = [{
  id: 1,
  child: []
}];
let lastParent = array[0];

const handleArrayDepth = () => {
  const { id, child } = lastParent;
  lastParent = { id: id + 1, child: [] };
  child.push(lastParent);
};

handleArrayDepth();
handleArrayDepth();
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you so much for your answer! But `const array` itself can have more objects. So using `array[0]` might need another loop for `array` on those case.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the closure function instead

```js
const data = [];

const handleArrayDepth = (function() {
    let id = 1;
    return function(arr) {
        if (!arr.length) {
            arr.push({ id: id, child: [] });
        } else {
            id = arr[0].id + 1;
            handleArrayDepth(arr[0].child);
        }
    }
})();

function handleClick() {
 const ul = document.getElementById("list");
 let item = document.createElement("li");
 handleArrayDepth(data);
 item.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
 ul.appendChild(item);
}

document.getElementById("handler").addEventListener("click", handleClick);
```

```css
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

ul li {
 padding: 10px 10px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 margin: 5px 0;
 border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<button id = "handler">Click Me!</button>
<ul id = "list">

</ul>
```